# Count by group and subgroup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to generate some stats regarding some data I have in a model

I want to create stats according to an association and a status column.

i.e.

```
Model.group(:association_id).group(:status).count
```

to get an outcome like

```
[{ association_id1 => { status1 => X1, status2 => y1 } },
 { association_id2 => { status1 => x2, status2 => y2 } }...etc
```

Not really bothered whether it comes out in as an array or hash, just need the numbers to come out consistently. 
Is there a 'rails' way to do this or a handy gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Worked out something a little better, though happy to take advice on how to clean this up.

```
group_counts = Model.group(["association_id","status"]).count
```

This returns something like:

```
=> {[nil, "status1"]=>2,
[ass_id1, "status1"]=>58,
[ass_id2, "status7"]=>1,
[ass_id2, "status3"]=>71 ...etc
```

Which, while it contains the data, is a pig to work with.

```
stats = group_counts.group_by{|k,v| k[0]}.map{|k,v| {k => v.map{|x| {x[0][1] => x[1] }}.inject(:merge) }}
```

Gives me something a little friendlier

```
=> [{
 nil => {
  "status1" => 10,
  "status2" => 23},
 "ass_id1" => {
  "status1" => 7,
  "status2" => 23
}...etc]
```

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly, inefficient and there must be a better way to do it, but...

```
Model.pluck(:association_id).uniq.map{ |ass| { 
  name:(ass.blank? ? nil : Association.find(ass).name), data: 
    Model.where(association_id:ass).group(:status).count 
} }
```

Gives what I need. 
Obviously if you didn't need name the first term would be a little simpler.

i.e.

```
 Model.pluck(:association_id).uniq.map{ |ass| { 
   id:ass, data:Model.where(association_id:ass).group(:status).count 
 } }
```